# Role based access to FireStore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to implement role based access to Firebase Firestore but although I took a look at Googles well done documentation I wasn't able to get it working.
I have set a string "role" in each users document. The document itself has the uid of the user.

My rule to access the users collection looks like this and the write rule must be wrong:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{document} {
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.id)/role/$(role)) == "Mitarbeiter"
   }
  }
}
```

[image: FireStore]

XCode-console error:

```
[Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at users/EStQNC4cYcaSnKpxs4XnQf96brm2 failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Comment: Security rules are useless without client code that the rules should allow or deny.  Please edit the question to show the query that isn't working the way you expect, so we can see where they might be in conflict.

Comment: Also I **strongly** suggest using the UID of the user and not their email address in order to assign permissions.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added the code from Swift and adjusted it and my FireStore database to the uid.

Comment: Your rule is checking for the role in a document in a subcollection called "role", but you don't seem to have one.  You have a role field in the user's document itself.  What is your rule actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to assign a variable userData.accountLevel in Swift to the value of the FireStore entry "role" of the logged in user. Only a user with the role "Mitarbeiter" in its own users-collection document shall be allowed to read the value. Later I want to make it more complex/useful, but for the moment I just wanted to understand the syntax to use the "role" field in the user's document itself as the access indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of your document `get()` is looking inside a subcollection called "role", but you have none:

```
/users/$(request.auth.id)/role/$(role)
```

Also, you have no variable called "role" that we can see here.

Using what you've shown, it looks like the role you need is in the document itself, so there's no need for a `get()`.  Just check it like this:

```
allow read: if resource.data.role == "Mitarbeiter";
```